# datatables responsive responsivePriority wont work

Tags: jquery, datatables

i use datatables and now i want to make my table responsive and set for some columns priority.

I've trie all the ways from the datatables examples, but everytime the columns hide from right to left. Everytime the first one/two columns still in view at the end of minimize the browsersecreen.

All my settings will ignore or wont work.

Thats the table

```
<table id="contacts_list" class="table responsive table-bordered table-hover" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th style="width:5rem;">text1</th>
                <th style="width:5rem;">text2</th>
                <th>text3</th>
                <th>text4</th>
                <th>text5</th>
                <th>text6</th>
                <th>text7</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
...
</table>
```

Thats one of the tries to init the table with column priority

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#contacts_list").DataTable(
        {
            responsive: true,
            columnDefs: [
                    { responsivePriority: 1, targets: -2 }
            ]           
        });

    });
```

Using `data-priority="1"` in the table th tag also not working for me.

What could be the reason for this ?

Comment: It looks like you are missing letters.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the problem using your example - it woks as expected for me. Can you [edit] the question to provide a [mre], or perhaps a code [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: @andrewjames that a real  problem on a fiddle it works well. so what can be the reason for that? I use bootstrap4 maybe this is a point?

Comment: Are you saying `responsive` works correctly when you do _not_ use bootstrap4, but fails to work when you _do_ use bootstrap4? If so, you can [edit] your question to clarify this, and to show the relevant code and libraries. Maybe also add the bootstrap4 tag to your question. (I don't use bootstrap, personally.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that i've include the wrong libaries. I've create a new libarie set from datatables-website and after inlcuding this files all works fine.